# Registering e-mail adress with my domain AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns

I am a begginner (18 y.o.) and I am lost in the AWS console. I have a static website on my domain, but I would like to have some emails ending with my domain, for example **mynameis@michaldang.cz**

In the SES Management Console I have verified my domain. In the Email adresses I have added e-mails that I want, but I do not know, how to verify them and redirect all the e-mails to my gmail.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Give some examples.

Comment: you should be looking at AWS workmail or Gsuite instead of SES.

Comment: Ok, I will do and will come back if any further questions occur. Thank you.